# SketchApp > iOS & Android workflows

Tags: android, ios, iphone, constraints, sketchapp

I am wondering how the usual design -> implementation process is handled.

I am having a designer that is working with [sketch](https://www.sketchapp.com/). And designers love to work pixel perfect. So far so goot. So he is creating dozens of screen designs for each iphone / ipad with absolute positions/dimensions. This lead to the question, **How should I implement this?**

I mean i can create one storyboard file for iPhone and another one for iPad. But i cannot create storyboards for each iPhone device. I mean even if I could it would be hell wouldn't it?

Now I thought working with relative constraints would lead to the situation the he and me will have to work with 2 designs only (one for iPad one for iPhone), well then I found out the plugin "[Fluid](https://github.com/matt-curtis/Fluid-for-Sketch)" for SketchApp which allows working like in XCode.

Now he is wondering how to change his workflow, because he cant work pixel perfect with absolute positions.

**Whats your best practice to handle the designers workflow in sketch. Do you ask them to work with relative values? Do you convert the absolute px values by yourself? Did I miss something?**

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're a developer? What exactly are you trying to implement this file into?

The designer shouldn't be worrying about absolute positioning. The designer should simply know what your designing for and what assets you need output as deliverables.

I use sketch it one of two ways...

1. My file is always live on InVision where my developers can go in a view it in developer mode to get the full color palette, font listing, and some CSS-translated code for reference use during the development process.
2. I export sections of the design as SVG for use in things like XCode or Android Studio.

So really the best practice depends on what your end goal is. It's very unclear from your OP however.